# Multiplying jquery functions for different divs (one function many divs)

Tags: jquery, html, function

I have a question about not multiplying jquery functions:

I wrote a code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#pic1").click(function(){
    $("#content1").fadeIn(1500);});
$("#pic2").click(function(){
    $("#content2").fadeIn(1500);});
$("#pic3").click(function(){
    $("#content3").fadeIn(1500);});
})
```

I can't add classes because when I click one div I want to fadeIn another div (but only one)

Is it possible to write it easier especially that I have 50 pic and 50 content;

and the second a little similar question:

I have a code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#obraz1").click(function(){
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:450}, 1500);});
$("#obraz2").click(function(){
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:450}, 1500);});
$("#obraz3").click(function(){
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:450}, 1500);});
$("#obraz4").click(function(){
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:730}, 1500);});
$("#obraz5").click(function(){
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:730}, 1500);});
$("#obraz6").click(function(){
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:730}, 1500);});
$("#obraz7").click(function(){
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:1000}, 1500);});
$("#obraz8").click(function(){
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:1000}, 1500);});
$("#obraz9").click(function(){
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:1000}, 1500);});
})
```

the same questions - any idea to do it easier if I have 50-70 divs? 
thanks in advance

Comment: give them the same class and target the class, use a foreach and leverage the this keyword to target the exact one that is clicked.

Comment: Your reason for not being able to add a class is not valid. I'd suggest adding a class to the relevant elements. Then on those html elements you could also add data attributes which you could fetch with jQuery's `.data()` function. Alternatively as you're only changing numbers in subsequent triggers, you could make use of the elements index to reference the div you want to do stuff on, still using a class. No need for loops here.

Comment: @Łukasz Bogocz please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See @Nishit Maheta's answer for the second question.

As for the first issue, you could do the following;

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tdmpcqwd/)

**HTML**

```
<div class='pic_click'>1</div>
<div class='pic_click'>2</div>
<div class='pic_click'>3</div>
<div class='pic_click'>4</div>
<div class='pic_click'>5</div>

<br />

<img id='content1' src='http://lorempixel.com/300/200/sports/' />
<img id='content2' src='http://lorempixel.com/300/200/nightlife/' />
<img id='content3' src='http://lorempixel.com/300/200/food/' />
<img id='content4' src='http://lorempixel.com/300/200/city/' />
<img id='content5' src='http://lorempixel.com/300/200/cats/' />
```

**JS**

```
$('.pic_click').on('click', function() {
    $('#content' + ($(this).index() + 1)).fadeIn(1500);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for divs=content1, content2, etc; for img works perfectly ;)

Comment: @ŁukaszBogocz It works almost exactly the same for `div`s [see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49pqnn09/)

Answer (score 1):

try with below code. assign scroll value as attribute of div. See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3Lajv2bt/) on [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3Lajv2bt/)

```
$(document).ready(function({
    $("div[id^='obraz']").click(function(){
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(this).attr('data-scroll')}, 1500);
    });

    $("div[id^='pic']").click(function(){
      $("#content"+$(this).attr('data-index')).fadeIn(1500);
    }); 
});

<div id="obraz1" data-scroll="450"> val1 </div>
<div id="obraz2" data-scroll="750"> val1 </div>
<div id="obraz3" data-scroll="1000"> val1 </div>

<div id="pic1" data-index="1"> val1 </div>
<div id="pic2" data-index="2"> val1 </div>
<div id="pic3" data-index="3"> val1 </div>
```